# Share a compressed (zip) file

Tags: codenameone, share

I want to save user data compressed into the cloud.
Previously as recommended by Shai I compress it then used the `Share API` to bring it to the cloud.
After the compression, I know the name of the compressed file.
If I pass it as the first (text) parameter of the `share` method, it will share the file name as text.
If I pass it as the second (image) parameter of the `share` method, it will share as file but name of file will be prefixed. Regardless of what mime type I set.
For example, the compressed file is named `IMG_20200119_173716_salontables.zip`.
Do it this way?
If so, how do I avoid adding a prefix?

Best regards
Péter

Answer (score 1):

I think this was done to keep file names unique as we move them to the shared folder. I made a change that will keep the existing name in a case where the name is unique. It should be up in the coming Friday release.

Comment: Hí,  
It is important to keep the filename unique.  
I was disturbed that the name start with "IMG" all cases.  
I'm not an ios expert.But I see that the form "name.exception" is a common occurrence in ios like android.  
I recommend that the place of "_date_time" tag before the last dot. For example ```salontables_20200119_173716.zip```.  If there is no dot then at the end of the name.
Best regards  
Péter